# Game strategy of incrementing to coprime numbers with $N=3$: does the second player always have a winning strategy?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, game-theory, coprime

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They take $M$ turns, starting with one point each. The winner is the player with the highest score at the end of the game. In each round the players can make "increments" up to $N=3$ times. Incrementing means increasing your score to the next number that is coprime to your opponent's score. For example, if you have $7$ points and your opponent has $12$, one increment would result in you having $11$ points.

In a $N=3, M=2$ game, the optimal play is for Alice and Bob to increment $2, 3, 3, 3$ times. The scores are: $1-1 \rightarrow 3-1 \rightarrow 3-5 \rightarrow 7-5 \rightarrow 7-9 $, so Bob wins. Alice chooses not to make the three increments in Round 1, as she would score $4$ points and Bob would be allowed to make three increments: $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 7$.

Using a computer to compute optimal strategies up to about $M<1000$, it appears that there is always a winning strategy for Bob, regardless of the value of $M$. This is interesting because for most combinations of $N$ and $M$, Alice has a winning strategy. My question is whether it is true that, for $N=3$, Bob always has a winning strategy regardless of the value of $M$. (I am also interested in $N$ values for which Bob has a winning strategy for any $M$. I am considering asking a separate question about this.)

---

Update

I posted a proof to this question last week, but I have found a flaw in it. I have highlighted the problematic part in bold.

> Thanks to helpful comments, I was able to come up with a proof.
>
> Let $A_i$ and $B_i$ denote the scores of Alice and Bob, respectively, at the end of the $i$-th round. Suppose for a particular $i$, $B_i$ is odd and $B_i >= A_i + 2$.
>
> In this case, since $B_i-1$, $B_i+1$, and $B_i+2$ are pairwise coprime with $B_i$, Alice cannot step over these values. Consequently, her score in the next round is limited by $A_{i+1} <= B_i + 2$.
>
> If $A_{i+1} <= B_i$, **Bob can increment his score twice or three times to ensure that $B_{i+1} >= A_{i+1} + 2$, and $B_{i+1}$ is odd**.
>
> If $A_{i+1} = B_i + 1$, then $A_{i+1}$ is even. In this case, Bob can increment his score twice, ensuring that $B_{i+1} >= A_{i+1} + 3$, and $B_{i+1}$ is odd.
>
> If $A_{i+1} = B_i + 2$, Bob's second increment skips $A_{i+1}$, so $B_{i+1} = B_i + 4 = A_{i+1} + 2$. This also guarantees that $B_{i+1}$ is odd.
>
> Since the initial condition $B_i >= A_i + 2$ and $B_i$ being odd are satisfied at $i=1$, it follows that for all $i$, $B_i >= A_i + 2$.

The bold section would be incorrect, for example, in cases where $A_{i+1}=55$ and $B_i=73$. In such a scenario, $B_{i+1}$ can only be $74$, $76$, or $78$, and it cannot be an odd number.

Comment: Are Alice and Bob allowed to stall? e.g. by skipping their turn. If so, then Alice will always win.

Comment: Can you clarify your use of the term "coprime"? Coprime to what?

Comment: I'm guessing that for $N = 3$, the optimal play is to increment $2, 3, 3, 3, \ldots $ times. The idea is that if you end on an even number, then that allows your opponent to increase by much higher, and you won't be able to catchup. You'd only be able to increase by 3 each time, unless 1/ They have an even number, 2/ They have a multiple of 3 and you're quite behind, 3/ They have some other composite number and you're very far behind.

Comment: @AaaLol_dude I had assumed that at least one increment must be made, but even allowing zero increments, it seems that there is still a winning strategy for Bob.

Comment: @quasi Thank you for feedback. By "coprime" I mean mutually prime with respect to the opponent's score. I have also revised the wording of the question. Does that make things clearer for you?

Comment: I feel this can be a strategy: First Alice goes to $3$, (going to even is a disaster), then Bob goes to $5$, then Alice doesn't go to even, so she needs to go to $7$. In general, one can prove that from $(2n-1,2n+1)$ Alice goes to $(2n+3,2n+1)$ then Bob goes to $(2n+3,2n+5)$. This is possible since $\gcd(2n+1,2n) = \gcd(2n+1,2n+2) = \gcd(2n+1,2n+3) = 1$. (If Alice makes an empty move, Bob does the same). The only trouble is proving Alice never decides to go to an even number

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for the comment. Upon testing with small values of $M$, it seems that adopting a strategy to maximize your scores leads to the optimal play of incrementing $2, 3, 3, 3,\ldots$ as you pointed out.

Comment: I think that going to an even number is not an optimal strategy can be proven using casework