# What is $N=1,3,5,9,17,77,105,111,429,455\ldots$, where the second player (possibly) always wins in a game involving incrementing to coprime numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, game-theory, coprime

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They take $M$ turns, starting with one point each. The winner is the player with the highest score at the end of the game. In each round the players can make "increments" one times to $N$ times. Incrementing means increasing your score to the next number that is coprime to your opponent's score. For example, if you have $7$ points and your opponent has $12$, one increment would result in you having $11$ points.

In a $N=3, M=2$ game, for instance, the optimal play is for Alice and Bob to increment $2, 3, 3, 3$ times. The scores are: $1-1 \rightarrow 3-1 \rightarrow 3-5 \rightarrow 7-5 \rightarrow 7-9 $, so Bob wins. Alice chooses not to make the three increments in Round 1, as she would score $4$ points and Bob would be allowed to make three increments: $1\rightarrow 3\rightarrow 5\rightarrow 7$.

I found that for most of $M$ and $N$ Alice wins, but for some $N$s Bob seems to win regardless of the value of $M$.
I computed the winning strategy on PC, then the results is that $N=1,3,5,8,17,77,105,111,429,455$ are the numbers that Bob wins for at lease about $M<100$.

My question is whether there is a pattern in the numbers that Bob wins. I've only investigated for $M<100$, so I haven't confirmed whether these values are correct yet. However, I'm also interested in understanding for which $N$ Bob consistently wins up to a certain $M$.

My try:

For the case where $N=1$, it is obvious that Bob wins. Because Alice and Bob can and must increment $1$ times in each round, so the score of Alice and Bob increase by $2$ in each round.

For the case where $N=3$, I have asked another question: [Game strategy of incrementing to coprime numbers with $N=3$: does the second player always have a winning strategy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4805180/679357) I have been able to prove to some extent, but it is not yet complete.

The results are as follows. A means Alice wins, B means Bob wins. The values of $N$ are indicated in the first column, and horizontally $M$ increases. Due to character limits, results ending in "A" have been omitted.

Some of the cases where $N$ is large cannot be computed up to $M<100$ due to insufficient memory. Calculations beyond this range are challenging as they consume a significant amount of memory.

```
1:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
2:B,A...
3:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
4:B,A...
5:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
6:B,A...
7:B,A,A,B,A...
8:B,A...
9:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
10:B,A...
11:B,B,A,A,B,A...
12:B,B,A...
13:B,B,A...
14:B,B,A...
15:B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,A...
16:B,A...
17:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
18:B,A...
19:B,A...
20:B,B,A...
21:B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,A...
22:B,A...
23:B,B,A,B,A,B,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
24:B,A...
25:B,A...
26:B,A...
27:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A...
28:B,A...
29:B,B,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,A,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,B,A...
30:B,A...
31:B,A,B,B,B,A...
32:B,B,B,A...
33:B,B,B,A,A,A,B,A...
34:B,B,B,A...
35:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,A...
36:B,A...
37:B,A...
38:B,A...
39:B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
40:B,A,B,A...
41:B,B,B,A...
42:B,B,B,A...
43:B,B,B,A,A,A,B,A...
44:B,B,A...
45:B,B,A...
46:B,B,A...
47:B,B,A,B,B,A...
48:B,B,A...
49:B,A...
50:B,A...
51:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
52:B,A...
53:B,A,A,B,A...
54:B,A...
55:B,A...
56:B,A...
57:B,B,B,B,A...
58:B,A...
59:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,A,B,A...
60:B,B,A...
61:B,B,A...
62:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
63:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
64:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
65:B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,A...
66:B,A...
67:B,A...
68:B,A...
69:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A...
70:B,A,B,A...
71:B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,B,A...
72:B,B,A...
73:B,B,A...
74:B,B,B,A...
75:B,A...
76:B,A...
77:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
78:B,A...
79:B,A...
80:B,A...
81:B,B,B,B,B,A...
82:B,A...
83:B,A,A,B,A...
84:B,A...
85:B,A...
86:B,A...
87:B,B,B,B,A...
88:B,A...
89:B,A...
90:B,A...
91:B,A...
92:B,A...
93:B,A...
94:B,A...
95:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
96:B,A...
97:B,A...
98:B,A...
99:B,B,B,A...
100:B,A,B,A...
101:B,B,B,A...
102:B,B,B,B,A...
103:B,B,B,A...
104:B,B,B,A...
105:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
106:B,A...
107:B,B,A...
108:B,B,A...
109:B,B,A...
110:B,B,A...
111:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
112:B,A...
113:B,A...
114:B,A...
115:B,A...
116:B,A...
117:B,A,B,A...
118:B,A...
119:B,A,A,B,B,A...
120:B,B,B,A...
121:B,B,B,B,A...
122:B,B,B,B,A...
123:B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
124:B,B,B,B,B,A...
125:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,A...
126:B,A...
127:B,A...
128:B,A...
129:B,B,A...
130:B,B,A...
131:B,A,A,B,B,A...
132:B,A...
133:B,A...
134:B,A...
135:B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
136:B,A,A,B,A...
137:B,B,B,B,A...
138:B,A...
139:B,A,B,A...
140:B,B,B,A...
141:B,A...
142:B,A...
143:B,A...
144:B,A,B,B,B,A...
145:B,A,B,B,B,A...
146:B,B,B,B,A...
147:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
148:B,A...
149:B,B,A...
150:B,B,A...
151:B,B,A...
152:B,B,A...
153:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
154:B,B,A,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,A,B,A...
155:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,B,A,B,A,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,A...
156:B,A...
157:B,A...
158:B,A...
159:B,A,A,B,A...
160:B,A,B,B,B,B,A...
161:B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,B,A,B,A...
162:B,B,A...
163:B,B,A...
164:B,B,A...
165:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
166:B,A...
167:B,A...
168:B,B,A...
169:B,A...
170:B,A...
171:B,B,A...
172:B,B,A...
173:B,A...
174:B,A...
175:B,A...
176:B,A...
177:B,B,B,B,A...
178:B,A,B,A...
179:B,B,B,A,B,A...
180:B,B,B,B,B,A...
181:B,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,A...
182:B,B,A...
183:B,B,A...
184:B,B,A...
185:B,A...
186:B,A...
187:B,A...
188:B,B,B,A...
189:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,B,B,A...
190:B,A...
191:B,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,A...
192:B,B,B,B,A,B,A...
193:B,B,B,B,A,B,A...
194:B,B,A...
195:B,B,B,A...
196:B,B,B,A...
197:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
198:B,A...
199:B,A...
200:B,B,A...
201:B,A...
202:B,A...
203:B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A...
204:B,B,B,B,A...
205:B,B,B,B,A...
206:B,B,A...
207:B,B,A...
208:B,B,A...
209:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
210:B,A...
211:B,A...
212:B,A...
213:B,A...
214:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A...
215:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
216:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
217:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A...
218:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
219:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,
220:B,A...
221:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
222:B,A...
223:B,A...
224:B,A...
225:B,B,A,A,A,B,A...
226:B,B,A,B,A,B,A...
227:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
228:B,A...
229:B,A...
230:B,B,A...
231:B,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,A...
232:B,A...
233:B,A,B,A...
234:B,A...
235:B,A...
236:B,A...
237:B,B,A...
238:B,B,B,A...
239:B,B,A...
240:B,B,A...
241:B,B,A...
242:B,B,A...
243:B,B,A...
244:B,B,A...
245:B,A...
246:B,A...
247:B,A...
248:B,B,A...
249:B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A...
250:B,A...
251:B,A...
252:B,A...
253:B,A...
254:B,A...
255:B,B,B,B,B,A...
256:B,A...
257:B,A,A,B,B,A...
258:B,B,B,A...
259:B,B,B,A...
260:B,B,A...
261:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
262:B,A...
263:B,A,A,A,B,A,B,A,B,A...
264:B,A...
265:B,A...
266:B,B,B,A...
267:B,B,B,A,B,A...
268:B,B,B,A...
269:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
270:B,A...
271:B,A...
272:B,B,A...
273:B,B,A...
274:B,B,A...
275:B,B,A,A,A,B,A,B,A...
276:B,B,A...
277:B,B,A...
278:B,B,A...
279:B,B,A...
280:B,B,A...
281:B,B,A,A,B,A...
282:B,B,B,A...
283:B,B,B,A...
284:B,B,B,A...
285:B,A...
286:B,A...
287:B,A,A,B,B,B,A...
288:B,A...
289:B,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A...
290:B,B,B,B,B,A...
291:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
292:B,A...
293:B,A...
294:B,A...
295:B,A...
296:B,A...
297:B,A...
298:B,A...
299:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
300:B,A...
301:B,A...
302:B,A...
303:B,A...
304:B,A...
305:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,B,A,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,A...
306:B,A...
307:B,A...
308:B,A...
309:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
310:B,A...
311:B,B,A...
312:B,B,B,A...
313:B,B,B,A...
314:B,B,B,A...
315:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
316:B,A...
317:B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
318:B,B,A...
319:B,B,A...
320:B,B,A...
321:B,B,A...
322:B,B,A,B,A...
323:B,A...
324:B,A...
325:B,A...
326:B,A...
327:B,A...
328:B,A...
329:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A...
330:B,A...
331:B,A...
332:B,A...
333:B,A,A,A,A,B,B,A...
334:B,A,A,A,A,B,A...
335:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,A...
336:B,A...
337:B,A,A,B,A...
338:B,A,A,B,A...
339:B,A,A,B,A...
340:B,A,A,B,A...
341:B,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
342:B,A...
343:B,A...
344:B,A...
345:B,B,B,B,B,A...
346:B,A...
347:B,B,A...
348:B,B,A...
349:B,B,A,A,A,B,A,A,B,A...
350:B,B,A,B,B,B,A...
351:B,B,A...
352:B,B,A...
353:B,B,A...
354:B,B,A...
355:B,A...
356:B,A...
357:B,B,A...
358:B,B,A...
359:B,A...
360:B,A...
361:B,A...
362:B,A...
363:B,A...
364:B,A...
365:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A...
366:B,A...
367:B,A...
368:B,A...
369:B,A...
370:B,A...
371:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,B,A...
372:B,A...
373:B,A...
374:B,A...
375:B,A...
376:B,B,A...
377:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,B,B,A...
378:B,A...
379:B,A...
380:B,A...
381:B,B,B,B,A,B,B,A...
382:B,B,B,A...
383:B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
384:B,B,B,A...
385:B,A...
386:B,A...
387:B,B,B,B,A...
388:B,A...
389:B,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,B,A...
390:B,B,A...
391:B,B,A...
392:B,B,A...
393:B,B,A...
394:B,B,B,A...
395:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
396:B,A...
397:B,A...
398:B,B,A...
399:B,B,A...
400:B,B,A...
401:B,B,A,A,B,A...
402:B,B,A,B,B,A...
403:B,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,B,A,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,A...
404:B,B,A...
405:B,B,A...
406:B,B,A...
407:B,B,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,A...
408:B,A...
409:B,A,B,B,A...
410:B,B,B,A,B,B,A...
411:B,A...
412:B,A...
413:B,A...
414:B,A...
415:B,A...
416:B,A...
417:B,B,B,B,A,B,A...
418:B,A,B,B,A...
419:B,B,B,A...
420:B,B,A...
421:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,A,A,B,A...
422:B,B,A...
423:B,B,A...
424:B,B,A...
425:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
426:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
427:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
428:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,B,A,A,B,B,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A...
429:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
430:B,A...
431:B,B,A,A,A,B,B,B,B,A...
432:B,B,B,A...
433:B,B,B,A,B,A...
434:B,B,A,B,B,A...
435:B,B,A,B,B,A...
436:B,B,A...
437:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,A,B,A...
438:B,A...
439:B,A...
440:B,A...
441:B,B,B,B,B,A...
442:B,A,A,A,B,A...
443:B,A,A,B,B,A...
444:B,A,A,B,A...
445:B,A,A,B,A...
446:B,A,B,A...
447:B,B,B,A...
448:B,B,B,A...
449:B,B,B,B,A...
450:B,B,B,A...
451:B,B,B,A...
452:B,B,B,A...
453:B,B,B,A...
454:B,B,B,A...
455:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,
456:B,A...
457:B,A...
458:B,A...
459:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,A...
460:B,A...
461:B,B,A,A,A,A,A,B,A,A,A,A,B,A...
462:B,B,A...
463:B,B,A...
464:B,B,A,B,A...
465:B,B,B,B,A...
466:B,B,B,A...
467:B,B,B,A...
468:B,B,B,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,B,A...
469:B,A...
470:B,A...
471:B,A...
472:B,A...
473:B,A...
474:B,A...
475:B,A...
476:B,A...
477:B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,A...
478:B,A...
479:B,A...
480:B,A...
481:B,A...
482:B,A...
483:B,A...
484:B,A...
485:B,B,B,B,A,B,A,B,B,B,B,B,A...
486:B,A...
487:B,A...
488:B,A...
489:B,B,B,B,B,A...
490:B,B,B,A...
491:B,A...
492:B,A...
493:B,A...
494:B,A...
495:B,A,B,B,B,B,A...
496:B,B,B,B,A...
497:B,B,B,B,B,B,A,B,A...
498:B,A...
499:B,A...
500:B,A...
```